# Django request.GET and jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, python, django, datatables

Considering the example [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) to fill up the jQuery-Datatables table with data provided by the server, a typical request has the following form:

```
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php?draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=10&length=10&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1406235319463
```

Which is the best way to deal with this kind of data, when Django is listening to the the client requests?

With the legacy Datatables [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side), I could easily deal with the request, by creating a form like the following and filling it with the request.GET data, to easily handle the validation and casting.

```
class DataTablesForm(forms.Form):
    iDisplayStart = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    iDisplayLength = forms.IntegerField(min_value=-1)
    iSortingCols = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=3)
    mDataProp_0 = forms.CharField()
    mDataProp_1 = forms.CharField()
    mDataProp_2 = forms.CharField()
    iSortCol_0 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=0, max_value=5)
    iSortCol_1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=0, max_value=5)
    iSortCol_2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=0, max_value=5)
    sSortDir_0 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=(('asc', 'asc'), ('desc', 'desc')))
    sSortDir_1 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=(('asc', 'asc'), ('desc', 'desc')))
    sSortDir_2 = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=(('asc', 'asc'), ('desc', 'desc')))
    sEcho = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

and

```
input_form = DataTablesForm(request.GET)
```

How do I deal though with the [new](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) format, i.e. "columns[i].name", which replaces the [old](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) "mDataProp_(int)"?

I think the problem is how to deal with JSON formatted GET data within Django, if "JSON formatted GET data" makes any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case I solved as following:

```
class DataTablesForm(forms.Form):

    draw = forms.IntegerField()
    length = forms.IntegerField()
    start = forms.IntegerField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataTablesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['_'] = forms.CharField()

        for i in range(0, 3):
            self.fields['columns[%d][data]' % i] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['columns[%d][name]' % i] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['columns[%d][orderable]' % i] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
            self.fields['columns[%d][search][regex]' % i] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
            self.fields['columns[%d][search][value]' % i] = forms.CharField(required=False)
            self.fields['columns[%d][searchable]' % i] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

            self.fields['order[%d][column]' % i] = forms.IntegerField(required=False, min_value=0, max_value=2)
            self.fields['order[%d][dir]' % i] = forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices=(('asc', 'asc'), ('desc', 'desc')))

        self.fields['search[regex]'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
        self.fields['search[value]'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```